# Database design for meeting room booking system

Tags: mysql

I am designing a table to store meeting room booking details to store bookings 
for single and multiple dates and time slots. For example user may book meeting room on single date e.g. on 2019-07-11 from 07:00:00 to 10:00:00 and may also book for multiple dates with same time slots e.g. on 2019-07-12,
2019-07-13, and 2019-07-14 from 11:00:00 to 12:00:00 each day.

I have design following two tables for same purpose with sample data for reference-

```
table 1:
--------------------------------------------------------
roomno | datefrom   | dateto     | timefrom | timeto   | 
--------------------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-11 | 2019-07-11 | 07:00:00 | 10:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-12 | 2019-07-14 | 11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------------------


table 2:
--------------------------------------------
roomno | datefrom   |  timefrom | timeto   | 
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-11 |  07:00:00 | 10:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-12 |  11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-13 |  11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
room1  | 2019-07-14 |  11:00:00 | 12:00:00 |
--------------------------------------------
```

I want to ask which table is less complex and simple to code which allow me to check what room is booked on which dates and time slots and display available time slots to user. At present I am facing trouble with selecting the records from table 1. Please suggest if other table schema should be used.

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking the two configurations?  When you say "efficient" I'm assuming you mean fastest?  Table2 will obviously be less efficient w/r/t storage if you expect lots of multi-day bookings.  Table2 is likely to move some of the app logic out of the database and into whatever language you're using, which is generally considered to be a good thing and may make maintenance easier.  What do you expect your `select`s to look like?

Comment: @A C thanks for comment. "efficient" means "less complex and simple to code". I want my SELECT to be simpler and even the required code. I will use PHP for app logic.